# Use an ActionCableClient connection for logging and receiving data alongside the main application

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, actioncable

when I start my application, I want ActionCable to transfer the logging to the server with a constant connection.

With this connection i want to interact with - sending actions and reading received messages on demand.

Since I have hardly dealt with EventMachine so far and found nothing on the Internet about my problem, here my question.

I will describe my problem/solution with a mix of real ruby and ruby pseudo code.

```rb
require 'action_cable_client'

my_thread = Thread.new do
  EventMachine.run do
    @@message_storage = []
    uri = "ws://127.0.0.1:3000/cable"
    client = ActionCableClient.new(uri, 'LoggingChannel')

    client.connected do
      puts 'successfully connected.'
    end

    client.disconnected do
      puts 'disconnected.'
    end

    client.received do |message|
      puts "Got a message: #{message}"
      @@message_storage += [message]
    end
  end
end

# here is my main app loop

some_actions()

if error
  my_thread.client.perform('error', {message: 'error 123 occured'})
end

if warning
  my_thread.client.perform('info', {message: 'some information for you'})
end

puts "Currently there are #{my_thread.@@message_storage.size} messages in storage"
```

Is there a solution?

**Additional information, my intention:**

I didn't figure out (so there is only pseudo code for it, that logically looks fine)

- how i can interact with the ActionCable inside the EventMachine to perform a task in it from outside
- how i can access a value inside the EventMachine/ActionCable from outside

Comment: What is your question? Can you explain it in words rather than cause us to have to decipher your code/pseudo code combination to determine your intention?

Comment: What exactly is not working with your code? The general approach looks fine to me.

Comment: @engineersmnky - i didn't figure out, how to interact with the EventMachine to get values from it and how to perform actions inside it from outside.So my pseudo code looks logical fine, but i didn't find a way to achieve this solution.

Comment: Why ActionCable? It seems to me that the overhead isn't something you need. You're customizing you messages anyway, might as well use raw WebSocket messages with your own simple JSON based protocol. This will also remove all the "magic" bits and make the communication easier to "grok". If you need Pub/Sub, consider using the iodine client/server (note: I'm biased).